# ajax not working after release

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

following is my code which works in Visual studio, but not working when I release it to our test environment.

**myview.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId,
        new SelectList(Model.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName"),
        " -- please choose a country-- ",
        new { onchange = "CountryDDLChanged()",  @class = "form-control" })
```

**JavaScript**

```
  function CountryDDLChanged() {

var url = '@Url.Content("~/Country/GetCitiesByCountryId")';
var countryid = $("#CountryId").val();
var ddlTarget = $("#CityId");

$(ddlTarget).empty();

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Country/GetCitiesByCountryId",
    data: { countryId: countryid },
    success: function (result) {
        ddlTarget.append("<option  value=''> -- please choose a city -- </option>");

        $.each(result, function (index, city) {
            ddlTarget.append("<option value='" + city.CityId + "'>" + city.CityName+ "</option>");
        });

        $("#cityDiv").show('slow');
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
 });
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public JsonResult GetCitiesByCountryId(int countryId)
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        using (var db = new PetaPoco.Database("myconnection"))
        {
            List<City> cities = db.Fetch<City>("Select * from City where CountryId = @0", countryId);
            result.Data = cities;
            result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It goes in to error handler and shows the alert message Not found I debugged the JavaScript in test environment it has staus 404

Comment: You created a `url` variable in your JS, but did not use it in the `$.ajax` call. Was that intentional?

Comment: I did not use it because when I use it I get same error on my Dev (VS) as our test environment. I changed it to what I used then it worked in VS.

Comment: Propblem solved: It worked When I changed the url to '../Country/GetCitiesByCountryId' in my JS

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `@Url.Action(....`

> It Generates a fully qualified URL to an action method.

```
@Url.Action("GetCitiesByCountryId","Country")
```

This works if your code is in razor view and not in `js` file. If you are calling function in `js` file . You can pass url to that `function` from `razor` code

Comment: Thank you Nitin, I have already tested that and it did not work. I think it didn't work in our test environment because test environment is is a virtual directory and we have used url redirect to go to our test

Answer (score 0):

Propblem solved: It worked When I changed the url to '../Country/GetCitiesByCountryId' in my JS.

I think it didn't work in our test environment because test environment is is a virtual directory and we have used url redirect to go to our test